# how to categorize "tastekid" and "clerkdogs" recommender system

Tags: recommendation-engine

I wonder what category of recommender system do Tastekid and clerkdogs belong to? Both do not seem to require any rating from users.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure about Clerkdogs but Tastekid seems to be a collaborative filtering system (see [here](http://wikibin.org/articles/tastekid.html)). Even when users don't provide ratings you can still apply collaborative filtering techniques. For instance, you can use a binary representation where 1 means a user liked an item and 0 when they don't like it (or unknown).